# How to bind Kivy TreeView node expand event to function

Tags: python, treeview, kivy

I looked online and I am still stuck on how to bind 'on_node_expand' of TreeView to a function.

Is it possible to get the proper syntax?

```
def createSubNode(elemObj,designTree,parent=None):
    if type(elemObj) is (designClass.PathGroup):
        pass
    else:
        for (name, obj) in elemObj.items():
            subroot = designTree.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=name,font_size=12),parent)
            subroot.fbind('on_node_expand', bind_object)
            createSubNode(obj,designTree,subroot)

def bind_object(node):
    print("testing")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.app import App

    class TestApp(App):
        def build(self):
            designTree = TreeView(root_options=dict(text='Designs',font_size=12))
            designTree.size_hint = (1,None)
            designTree.bind(minimum_height=designTree.setter('height'))
            createSubNode(dsgnManObj, designTree)
            svRoot = ScrollView(size=(Window.width, Window.height))
            svRoot.add_widget(designTree)
            root = BoxLayout(orientation ='horizontal')
            root.add_widget(svRoot)
            return root

    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`on_node_expand` is an event on the TreeView, not on the node, so you shouldn't need to bind it on `subroot` objects, but only on the `designTree` object.

Comment: You're welcome, but please accept the answer if it solved your issue :)